# Счётчик даты и времени

Tags: php

Есть код счётчика времени и даты:

```
    $endOfDiscount = strtotime($bp_and_res); // дата окончания распродажи
$now = time(); // текущее время
$secondsRemaining = $endOfDiscount - $now; // оставшееся время

define('SECONDS_PER_MINUTE', 60); // секунд в минуте
define('SECONDS_PER_HOUR', 3600); // секунд в часу
define('SECONDS_PER_DAY', 86400); // секунд в дне

$daysRemaining = floor($secondsRemaining / SECONDS_PER_DAY); //дни, до даты
$secondsRemaining -= ($daysRemaining * SECONDS_PER_DAY);     //обновляем переменную

$hoursRemaining = floor($secondsRemaining / SECONDS_PER_HOUR); // часы до даты
$secondsRemaining -= ($hoursRemaining * SECONDS_PER_HOUR);     //обновляем переменную

echo("$daysRemaining дней, $hoursRemaining часов"); //печатаем сообщение


$endOfDiscount = strtotime($bp_and_rm_res); // дата окончания распродажи
$now = time(); // текущее время
$secondsRemaining = $endOfDiscount - $now; // оставшееся время

$daysRemaining_rm = floor($secondsRemaining / SECONDS_PER_DAY); //дни, до даты
$secondsRemaining = ($daysRemaining_rm * SECONDS_PER_DAY);     //обновляем переменную

$hoursRemaining_rm = floor($secondsRemaining / SECONDS_PER_HOUR); // часы до даты
$secondsRemaining -= ($hoursRemaining_rm * SECONDS_PER_HOUR);     //обновляем переменную

echo("$daysRemaining_rm дней, $hoursRemaining_rm часов"); //печатаем сообщение
```

По окончании выставленной даты и времени, он даёт минус. Например если поставить сегодняшнюю дату, то он будет выдавать "-1 день", завтра будет "-2 день" и т.п.
Как сделать, чтобы по окончании выставленной даты, он просто писал, например "Акция закончилась".

Answer (score 0):

Сам нашёл только такое решение:

```
   if($daysRemaining_rm<0){
    echo "Акция закончилась";
} elseif($daysRemaining_rm>0){
    echo $daysRemaining_rm;
}
```

Comment: и чем вас не устраивает данное решение?